# facebook page plugin increase max width

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible in first place to increase max-width of the page plugin?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

I need to show 5 latest posts in my website. what would be the best way to do this. I dont mind working with json format data.

I have tried changing data-width parameter and adding width in css and inline width. but no luck.

[Sandy Seeds](https://www.facebook.com/Sandy-Seeds-700950136659680/)

Comment: Note that max width is 500px

Comment: The max width is fixed at 500px. You can't go further than that, unless you grab the API and code it yourself.

Comment: could anyone show me a link that would help me grab latest posts using API? which api do I use? fb graph API?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/page/feed

Answer (score 0):

I think you wobt be able to go above the 500 facebook sets.

You are linking towards their plugin and they decided to set the max-widht to 500